# UIDatePicker with datasource?

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I am looking for a little help and I have searched around however found nothing on this so far. Maybe somebody can help.

So I wondered if there is a way to set a 'datasource' for the UIDatePicker. I want to create a date picker that only shows certain dates and times that are available, say for instance;

a view with

```
Thur 9 Aug: 0900, 0930, 1000, 1100, 1130, 1200

Fri 10 Aug: 0900, 0930, 1000, 1030, 1100, 1130, 1200
(No weekend)

Mon 13 Aug: 0900, 0930, 1000, 1030, 1100, 1130, 1200
```

Is this functionality supported by UIDatePicker or will I be looking at using UIPickerView instead?

Thanks,

A

*** Update: a good example is within Apples Apple Store app, you can select a Genius Bar appointment from a restricted value UIDatePicker ***

Comment: I think you'll have to use a `UIPickerView`, but maybe you can do some manipulation of the `UIDatePicker` when the a time you don't support is picked?  You can set the minute interval to 30 minutes easily, but completely removing them from the list I'm not so sure on the possibility of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a UIPickerView, [since UIDatePicker does not not inherit from UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) (which it says in the last sentence of the "Overview" in the Apple documentation which I linked for you).

UIPickerView is what uses a data source.

UIDatePicker has a built-in data source which developers can't touch.

I'm guessing Apple's App Store Genius Bar appointment functionality has to be done with a UIPickerView. While UIDatePicker does have "`maximumDate`", "`minimumDate`" & "`minuteInterval`" properties, there's no way to set a selection or range of available dates & times within a date picker.

Comment: Thanks! Will use UIPickerView then!